# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages whin install neo/pusher-beams

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - neo/pusher-beams v1.0.1 requires illuminate/notifications 5.5.* || 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/notifications[5.5.x-d
ev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41,
 v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.
20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, 
v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - neo/pusher-beams v1.0.2 requires illuminate/notifications 5.5.* || 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/notifications[5.5.x-d
ev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41,
 v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.
20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, 
v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - neo/pusher-beams v1.0.3 requires illuminate/notifications 5.5.* || 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/notifications[5.5.x-d
ev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41,
 v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - neo/pusher-beams v1.0.4 requires illuminate/notifications 5.5.* || 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/notifications[5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - neo/pusher-beams v1.0.0 requires illuminate/queue 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.* || 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/queue[5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - don't install illuminate/queue 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.3, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.3].
    - Installation request for neo/pusher-beams ^1.0 -> satisfiable by neo/pusher-beams[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 0):

composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary

It installed me ^7.5 version and now everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove neo/pusher-beams and use the same and new packages